# FeatureGroup polygon and polyline cannot be edited with Leaflet-draw

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-draw, leaflet-plugins

I don't have much experience in Leaflet and I'm trying to learn from my mistakes. I have multiple polygons (just polygons) and some that have a polyline on top of it grouped as a `featureGroup` like:

```
var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
var mark = L.polygon(otherPoly, { title: 'testSimple', fillColor: 'blue', fillOpacity: 0.5, weight:20, color: 'green', opacity: 0.5, fill: true});
drawnItems.addLayer(mark);
var featureGroup = new L.featureGroup();
L.polygon(poly, { title: 'test', fillColor: '#F16E60', fillOpacity: 0.5, weight:20, color: '#F16E60', opacity: 0.5, fill: true}).addTo(featureGroup);
L.polyline(poly, { color: 'black', weight: '5', opacity: 0.7, dashArray: "10 10", clickable: false }).addTo(featureGroup);
drawnItems.addLayer(featureGroup);

poly = [
   [27.409550697482818, -82.4161570071192],
   [27.408793809505223, -82.41609048836837],
   [27.40876330512483, -82.41643166538779],
   [27.409230402899265, -82.41645312305991],
   [27.409567856048245, -82.41651105870916]]
```

I also have the `drawControl`:

```
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
edit: {
    featureGroup: drawnItems,
    edit: {
        selectedPathOptions: {
            maintainColor: true,
            opacity: 0.3,
        }
    },
},
draw: {
    marker: false,
    polyline: false,
    rectangle: false,
    circle: false,
    circlemarker: false,
    polygon: {
        icon: new L.DivIcon({
            iconSize: new L.Point(10, 10),
            className: 'leaflet-div-icon leaflet-editing-icon'
        }),
        shapeOptions: { color: 'white', opacity: 0.3, fillOpacity: 0.5, weight: 20 },
        showArea: true,
    }
}
});
```

but the editing is not applying to the `polygon` from inside `featureGroup`.

[image]

Is there a way to edit the polygon from featureGroup? To remove the polyline when edit mode is on, and to allow the user to change polygon shape?

Comment: You edited question and added additional question about deleting. GIS SE site policy requires focused questions, which amongst other things means one question per question. Please put question back as it was, or it might be closed as not compliant with the site policy.

Comment: @TomazicM You are right. Sorry for that. I've made the changes. Also, thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaflet-draw plugin can work only with basic vector layers, which means that members of `drawnItems` layer can only be basic vector layers like polylines and polygons, not layer groups.

If you want to edit your combined polygon that consists of two different styled polygons, you have to edit only one and then modify coordinates of the other when the first one changes. For this you can use `draw:editvertex` event processing function.

To access polygon which goes with the modified border, border polygon is defined with custom option `polygon` which contains the polygon layer.

Relevant part of the code could then look something like this (tested):

```
var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup().addTo(map);
var featureGroup = new L.FeatureGroup().addTo(map);

var polygon = L.polygon(polyCoords, {
  title: 'test',
  fillColor: '#F16E60',
  fillOpacity: 0.5,
  weight:20,
  color: '#F16E60',
  opacity: 0.5,
  fill: true
}).addTo(featureGroup);      
var polygonBorder = L.polygon(polyCoords, {
  color: 'black',
  weight: '3',
  opacity: 0.7,
  fill: false,
  dashArray: "10 10",
  polygon: polygon
}).addTo(featureGroup);

drawnItems.addLayer(polygonBorder);      

map.on('draw:editvertex', function (event) {
  var poly = event.poly;
  if (poly.options.polygon) {
    var coords = poly.getLatLngs();
    poly.options.polygon.setLatLngs(coords);
  }
});
```

Here is working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/7o9g5a6v/

Comment: I've added your code but for me it draws only the dashed line, without the red one bellow. When editing (inside draw:editvertex) I get the error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getLatLngs')" because event.poly is undefined. I have 2 simple polygons (green), and one that is combined (red with dashed black line on top) and I need  edit and delete to work for both situations

Comment: Corrected code a bit.  See working JSFiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/7o9g5a6v